# javascript split by whitespaces 3 elements

Tags: javascript

I have some lines..
For example:

```
var line;
line = "INFO  2014-10-08 15:01:17,233 [localhost-startStop-1] Main directory: C:\WORKSPACE";
line = "ERROR 2014-10-08 15:01:16,646 [localhost-startStop-1] Cannot alter it is not a table.";
var headerArray = line.split("\\s", 3);
//headerArray returns array of 1 element "INFO  2014-10-08 15:01:17,233 [localhost-startStop-1] Main directory: C:\WORKSPACE"; don't know why..
```

But I want only {"INFO", "2014-10-08", "15:01:17,233"} and then {"ERROR", "2014-10-08", "15:01:16,646"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split after removing the rest.

```
var line = "ERROR 2014-10-08 15:01:16,646 [localhost-startStop-1] Cannot alter it is not a table.";
var arr = line.replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/\s\[.+$/,"").split(" ");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: check it on line = "INFO  2014-10-08 15:01:17,233 [localhost-startStop-1] Main directory: C:\WORKSPACE";
this line has 4 elements, not 3. The second element is empty

Comment: @Gwalk you've an extra space after `INFO` was it intended?

Comment: slow?? Anyway glad to have helped you :)

Comment: I'm testing it on 10000 records :D